# Passing a std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> Array in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am working on a SFML project right now, and I have to pass an array of RectangleShapes to a void function.

```
std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shape(16);  
void setProperties(shape);
```

The function isn't made yet, but Visual Studio is giving me an error though.

```
void setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes(16))
{
}
```

But this code doen't seem to work. It'd be nice if you could help me.

Comment: What's with the `(16)` in the function declaration? What do you think it means?

Answer (score 0):

```
void setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes(16))
```

You have a syntax error since the argument should be made of a type declaration an an optional name for the argument, but you have an extraneous `(16)`

```
void setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes)
```

but this will pass a copy of the `std::vector` to the function, which could be not what you want (since it's expensive). It's better to pass a reference or a const reference if you don't need to modify the vector, eg:

```
void setProperties(const std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>& shapes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The (16) calls the constructor for std::vector. You can't use a function call within a function definition, so you need to change:

```
void setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes(16)){ ... }
```

to

```
void setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes){ ... }
```

Comment: It now says "An incomplete type is not allowed" at "void setProperties(shape);

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your variable `shape`, you are passing the value 16 into the constructor for the class `std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>`. The constructor is a function that operates during the construction of the object.
However, when you declare the function `setProperties`, you are determining what parameters are passed into the function rather than initializing those parameters. You cannot provide arguments to the parameter's constructor when declaring it. Try declaring and defining your function like so:

```
void setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes)
{
    // Set properties here.
}
```

It's also worth noting that since you are passing by value, a copy of the vector will be passed into the function rather than the original vector... If you want the function to affect the value of `shape`, you should pass it by reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now. I don't know if it's a good solution, but it works for me.

I changed the `void` to `std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>`

So it is this now:

```
std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shape(16);  
shape = setProperties(shape);  

std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> setProperties(std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes)
{ ... }
```